# Jquery .on function not working

Tags: jquery

Tearing my hair out with this one! It's really simple and I'm sure I've missed something obvious, but for some reason the 'click' event on the code below doesn't work - when I click on the '.contacthead' element, absolutely nothing happens - no error messages or anything.

Any help would be most appreciated!

The code:

HTML Markup

```
 <table class='contactinfobox'>
  <tr id="courserow2">
   <th class="contacthead" id="coursehead2">Course:</th>
   <td class="contactdata" id="coursedata2">Test course</td>
  </tr> 
 </table>
```

Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.contactinfobox').on('click', '.contacthead', function(){
   alert('test');
  });
 });
```

Comment: Works here http://jsfiddle.net/vGqCz/

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Kqp8U/1/

Comment: whether the table is created dynamically

Comment: The issue is elsewhere, the posted code is fine.

Comment: which version of `jQuery` have you included?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using on() it's probably because your target element doesn't exist on DOM ready. I'd guess that `.contactinfobox` doesn't, either. Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.contacthead', function(){
   alert('test');
  });
});
```

You can substitute any ancestor of `.contactinfobox` that's available on DOM ready for `document` to improve performance.